# Laravel 5 IP range validation

Tags: validation, laravel, ip, laravel-5

Im using **Laravel 5** for my project and i need to use my own validation.  I have IP Range table. (*start_ip,end_ip*). i need to check my ip range is available. how can i validate ip range in **laravel 5**?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If your IP range table is only used to check if a given IP belongs to a network, here is a simpler approach by using the [IPset](https://packagist.org/packages/wikimedia/ip-set) package (`composer require wikimedia/ip-set`) :

```
Validator::extend('ip_range',function ($attribute, $value, $parameters){
        $ipset = new IPSet(array('192.168.1.0/24');
        return ($ipset->match($value));
```

I'm assuming here that you only have one network (as example `192.168.1.0/24`), if you have more you can put as much as you want in the array. A cleaner way would be to edit your table and replace your ips with cidr annotations, and update your code :

```
$ipset = new IPSet(DB::table('your_table')->lists('your_cidr_column'));
```

And of course don't forget

```
use DB;
use IPset\Ipset;
```

Answer (score -1):

Extend Validator with `ip_range` rule:

```php
Validator::extend('ip_range', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    $ip = ip2long($value);
    $start_ip = ip2long($parameters[0]);
    $end_ip = ip2long($parameters[1]);

    if (!$ip || !$start_ip || !$end_ip) {
        return false;
    }

    return ($ip >= $start_ip && $ip <= $end_ip);
});
```

Don't forget to add `ip_range` value to `lang/en/validation.php` to have human readable error message.